# Invalid or corrupted jarfile - Docker

Tags: java, docker, rest, dockerfile, dockerhub

i'm creating a docker image to my automation test project, but i always got the error below

Can you help me please?

Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile javarestassuredextentreport.jar

Obs: When i generating jar file, it comes do the folder Artifacts, bug i dragged to the target, is it correct?

My projetct is base on Rest Assured, TestNG, JUnit and to create this image, i'm using dockerfile-maven-plugin from spotity.com

Here are my code and path[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmHqy.png)

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javarestassuredextentreport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <repository>maven-4-openjdk-17</repository>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                <buildArgs>
                    <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230618</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-testng-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
RUN mkdir app
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD /target/${JAR_FILE} /app/javarestassuredextentreport.jar
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT java -jar javarestassuredextentreport.jar
```

Comment: running jar like that implies presence of entrypoint definition in META-INF/manifect.mf inside your jar.

Comment: Do you know how can I do this? @an

Comment: Jars are just regular zip archives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an executable jar. Your Maven pom.xml currently does not create it.

To get an executable jar, the archive needs to contain a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF that declares which of the jar's classes is the main class. While you could create instructions yourself to get the task done, Maven has easy to use functionality to achieve the same. Add this plugin to your pom.xml's plugins:

org.apache.maven.plugins
        maven-jar-plugin
        
          
            
              true
              com.mycompany.app.App

Of course you need to list your main class, not the one given in the example.
To verify if your jar is ready to be placed inside the container, just run

```
java -jar target/javarestassuredextentreport.jar
```

and expect your application to startup in a meaningful way. Only then proceed to wrap it into the container.

Comment: I resolved the issue tittle, but my project does not have a main class, it is an test project, but now i have the issue of the main class "no main manifest attribute, in /app/javarestassuredextentreport-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Do you know what i have to do know?

Comment: This is a very concise question that has been asked and answered many times. Check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=maven+executable+jar